# Is it possible to set a default time period in Cloud Watch?

Tags: monitoring, amazon-cloudwatch

I'm using Amazon Web Service's Cloud Watch tool to monitor server performance. Whenever I reopen our various Dashboards the time period is always set to the last 3 hours. For some dashboards this is a good default but for others, I'd like it to be a different time period. Changing the time period doesn't seem to save any attribute to the URL.

Is it possible to set the default time period for an AWS CloudWatch dashboard?